# awk or sed change field of file based on another input file

Tags: awk, sed, field

I have a sparse matrix ("matrix.csv") with 10k rows and 22 columns (1st column is "user", and the rest columns are called "slots" and contain 0s or 1s), like this:

```
user1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,...,0
user2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,...,0
user3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,...,0
...
```

Some of the slots that contain a "0" should be changed to contain a "1".
I have another file ("slots2change.csv") that tells me which slots should be changed, like this:

```
user1,3
user3,21
...
```

So for user1, I need to change slot3 to contain a "1" instead of a "0", and for user3 I should change slot21 to contain a "1" instead of a "0", and so on.

Expected result:

```
user1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,...,0
user2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,...,0
user3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,...,1
...
```

How can I achieve this using **awk** or **sed**?

tried

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{user=$1;slot2change=$2} NR!=FNR; /user/ slot2change==0{print $0} ' slots2change.csv matrix.csv
```

but I feel I am still far from a correct command...

Comment: We are not here to produce free scripts to your needs, instead we encourage people asking to search and try something. If you get stuck, we will be happy to help

Comment: edited with my try, but not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    NR==FNR{arr[$1]=$2;next}
    NR!=FNR {for (i in arr)
        if ($1 == i) {
            F=arr[i] + 1
            $F=1
        }
     print
    }
' slots2change.csv matrix.csv
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the input file "slots2change.csv" can contain different lines with the same user, I edited the post, I will think on how to solve it..

Comment: Changing rules after accepting an answer is a bit rude

Comment: I know, sorry for that

Comment: Done, reedited the original post and acceptedd the first answer, I will write a new question with the detailed info